# CSV writer writes set to a single row rather than multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am working on a web scraper for class.  I basically have to compile all of the http links from a website and write them to a csv. They also need to be de-duplicated which is why I'm using a set.  I have all the parts complete expect when it writes to the csv, the entire set of links writes to a single row rather than one link per row. Can someone review my code and tell me what i'm missing?  I cannot find a solution anywhere.

My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import urllib.parse

base_url = 'https://www.census.gov'

l = set()

r = requests.get("https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html")
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')

file = open('c996webscraper_writer.csv', 'w', newline="")

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    output = link.get('href')
    abs_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, output)
    l.add(abs_url)

with file:
    write = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',', lineterminator = '\r')
    write.writerow(['List of Links'])
    write.writerows([l])

file.close()
```

This is a printout of what's happening:

[CSV Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHYcP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import urllib.parse

base_url = 'https://www.census.gov'

l = list()

r = requests.get("https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html")
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')

file = open('c996webscraper_writer.csv', 'w', newline="")

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    output = link.get('href')
    abs_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, output)
    l.append(abs_url)

with file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(['List of Links'])
    for x in l:
        write.writerow([x])

file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I also have to remove duplicates from the list which is why I had l = set().

Comment: Please say what you did differently